# Facebook Object Debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We run a blog in the UK and have recently noticed that Facebook stopped pulling our post descriptions and images when an article is liked, shared etc.

Running the Facebook Object Debugger I get the following messages:

Response Code: 200

Errors That Must Be Fixed
Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

(In case you wish to see it for yourself, here is a link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heruni.com%2F)

Below is a copy of our code -- what are we doing wrong?

```
<?php
function is_facebook(){
    if(!(stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],'facebook') === FALSE)) {
        return true;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"<?php if(is_facebook()){echo ' xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"';}?>>

<head>

    <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />        

<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="374D59D3C3F26F6EFC410429D512A98C" />

    <?php if(is_facebook()){ ?>
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ) ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>"/>      
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="256997234347344"/>
    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you use gzip in your page, disable it and try again. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the markup which Facebook sees for your page:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heruni.com%2F

You don't need to do any is_facebook() conditional stuff here - the tags, and the namespace should just be made visible on the web to all HTTP clients, not just the Facebook scraper.

Remove all these conditionals, and you code should work.

Comment: I removed all the conditionals, but markup which Facebook sees seems unchanged: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heruni.com%2F

Comment: You're only returning one line as far as I can see: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
`

Comment: right, which means that i am doing something wrong. but i can't seem to find the mistake for why FB isn't pulling the data.